# Make a sliding barn door airtight?

Tags: insulation, doors, weather-resistant

I'm brainstorming for building a cabin this summer and am wondering if anyone has had luck making a sliding barn door airtight (or at least, pretty airtight).

One cabin design I've been pondering is a south facing shed style structure with a little deck on the front. I'd like to have a way to open a significant portion of the front during non-buggy seasons and am thinking making a portion of the front wall into a sliding barn door on a runner might be a way to do that. The kicker is that I am planning to insulate the place and use it once in a while in the winter, so avoiding drafts would be a plus.

Comment: You can get brush type seals or you can design the door to be clamped onto a seal.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike. What kind of a seal material would you use for the clamped set up?

Comment: And also, what kind of hardware for the clamp?

Comment: Clamps can be threaded or over-centre cams - whatever you want or based on what you want to pay... As for a seal - some rubber equivalent that is compressible but not too soft...

Comment: Would lift-slide doors do what you need? Or do you really need the overhead style track for aesthetics? I have installed this type that allowed 16' of open wall

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike and Jack. I'm thinking something more rustic in appearance with a track, yes. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: That type of hardware will limit how big of an opening you can go. How big of an open space were you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good picture showing the bottoms of the lift slide doors I installed. The 16' ones were on another job, these are only offer a 10' opening. The pics showing the upper half are kinda dark.

Is this something that may work for you?
[image: Liftslide1]

[image: Liftslide2]

[image: Liftslide3]

Comment: What do the lift and slide cost?  I've installed some before and they were pricey.  The sliding door systems like the eclipse systems run ~$800 per foot but that is the top end.  Kind of unclear if the OP is asking for a solid door that would slide or is picturing something that has a window.

Comment: I know it does not come cheap, I was installing GU brand, I think But if the OP wants a system that will seal up and operate smoothly, that is the way to go, unless the overhead hardware is a must. I would hope it would be closer to 800 bucks an operable panel